# Using Taylors to show convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, self-learning, weak-convergence, law-of-large-numbers

I'd like to show that 
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n} \left( (1-\frac{1}{n})^{n\bar{X}} - e^{-\bar{X}} \right) \to 0
\end{equation}
in probability for a random variable with mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$.

I believe this could be done with Taylors theorem though I'm not sure. Notice we can show using the continuous mapping theorem plus the law of large numbers that the quantity inside the paraenthesis converges to 0 in probability. The thing I can't get is how to show that even if we multiply it by $\sqrt{n}$ it still goes to 0.

Comment: I think you need something a bit less straightforward than the continuous mapping theorem to prove that the quantity inside the parenthesis converges to zero, since in its first element you have a composition of sequences of functions (both depending on $n$), and for the limit of the composition to converge to the composition of limits you need some additional conditions (they do hold here). And as Did noted, you should have only one minus signs - not two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a sign error in the problem, hence we consider $$Y_n=\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n\bar X_n}-\mathrm e^{-\bar X_n}.$$ Note that, when $n\to\infty$, $$\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)=-\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right),$$ hence $$\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n\bar X_n}=\exp\left(-\bar X_n-\frac{\bar X_n}{2n}+o\left(\frac{\bar X_n}n\right)\right),$$ Thus,
$$n\,Y_n\,\mathrm e^{\bar X_n}=n\,\left(\exp\left(-\frac{\bar X_n}{2n}+o\left(\frac{\bar X_n}n\right)\right)-1\right)=-\frac12\bar X_n+o\left(\bar X_n\right).$$
Note that $(\bar X_n)$ is almost surely bounded and that, by the strong law of large numbers for i.i.d. sequences, $\bar X_n\to\mu$ almost surely. Thus, almost surely, $$n\,Y_n\to-\frac12\mu\,\mathrm e^{-\mu}.$$ In particular, for every $\alpha\lt1$, $n^\alpha\,Y_n\to0$ almost surely, hence in probability.

Comment: I apologize if it's been misunderstood. $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean, so that goes to $\mu$ in probability. I don't understand how the last expression goes to $-\frac12\bar X$.

Comment: Ach so... And since $\bar X$ depends on $n$, you never say so at any moment? Hmmm... :-( See revised version.

Comment: Sorry lol, thanks, I just don't get this part $n\,\left(\exp\left(-\frac{\bar X_n}{2n}+o\left(\frac{\bar X_n}n\right)\right)-1\right)=-\frac12\bar X_n+o\left(\bar X_n\right)$. How did you know that expression is just $-\frac12\bar X_n+o\left(\bar X_n\right)$? There's an exp inside there..

Comment: Sure there is, and $e^u=1+u+o(u)$ when $u\to0$, hence $w(e^u-1)=wu+o(wu)$ for every $w$, to be used with $w=n$ and $u=-\bar X_n/n+o(\bar X_n/n)$ (such that $u\to0$ since $\bar X_n$ is bounded).

Comment: you are the king.